# using youtubes api on a website which runs on a raspberry pi

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use the youtube api to search for videos on my own page. That works so far quite well, as long as I access the site via localhost. I use PHPStorms build-in-server (which basically is xampp) to connect via localhost to the website. But if I run the page on my Raspberry Pi and do the same search, about 90% of the videos shows the following error: "video not available".

This is the code for the api

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) )
        {

          if (!empty($keyword))
          {
            $keyword = str_replace(' ', '',$keyword);
            $apikey = ' '; // i removed the key
            $googleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . $keyword . '&maxResults=' . MAX_RESULTS . '&key=' . $apikey;



            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
            $data = json_decode($response);
            $value = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
        ?>

        <div class="result-heading">About <?php echo MAX_RESULTS; ?> Results</div>
        <div class="videos-data-container" id="SearchResultsDiv">

        <?php

            for ($i = 0; $i < MAX_RESULTS; $i++) {
                if (!empty($value['items'][$i]['id']['videoId'])) {
                    $videoId = $value['items'][$i]['id']['videoId'];
                    $title = $value['items'][$i]['snippet']['title'];
                    $description = $value['items'][$i]['snippet']['description'];

                    ?>

                    <div class="video-tile">
                        <div class="videoDiv">
                            <iframe id="iframe" style="width:100%;height:100%"
                                    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoId; ?>"
                                    data-autoplay-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoId; ?>?autoplay=1"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoInfo">
                            <div class="videoTitle"><b><?php echo $title; ?></b></div>
                            <div class="videoDesc"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                }
            }

        }
        ?>

    </div>
```

does anyone know why it works on localhost but not on the raspberry pi?

Comment: I presume you are using apache on the pi, can you check your log file for any errors?

Comment: sounds like the pi is to slow to load it

Comment: @DaImTo But some videos are playable. It's always the same videos which are not available

Comment: @JensV I did that. Apache doesn't throw any error.